# Android layout mis-stretched on a small device

Tags: android, image, layout, stretch

I am developing an application for android. My main layout is a RelativeLayout.

When I'm opening the app for debug within a large-screen emulator, everything works fine.
But when I open it on a QVGA device, I see al the layout distorted.

Do I actually need to make a new layout for every screen size? I have seen at some places that android can automatically stretch everything to fit the layout...

Developer.android.com says:

> By default, Android resizes your application layout to fit the current device screen.

(http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Could you please help me figure out why a layout would look distorted ion a small device?
As you can see the images do get stretched, but the layout is not displayed well.

Thanks in advance!

[Big Screen Image http://www.interload.co.il/upload/6549026.png](http://www.interload.co.il/upload/6549026.png)
[Small Screen Image http://www.interload.co.il/upload/9617759.png](http://www.interload.co.il/upload/9617759.png)

**Edit:** XML code of the problematic page.
All the graphics are in "drawable-hdpi" folder, but again, the problem is not with the images themselves, but with the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/selectionHead"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/chooseFormatTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selectionHead"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/step1_choose_format" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/videoBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:onClick="VideoClick"
    android:src="@drawable/step1_video" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/orTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/videoBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:src="@drawable/step1_or" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/audioBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/orTxt"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/videoBtn"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="AudioClick"
    android:src="@drawable/step1_audio" />

<ImageView
    android1:id="@+id/step1Share"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/selectionHead"
    android1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android1:src="@drawable/share" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you had hard coded image position in your layout thats y its look different behavior.

Comment: Not enough info is given here--post your layout XML and let us know what folder(s) your drawables are in.

Comment: Try to be more specific when ever you had any query and also try to provide more details of your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I actually need to make a new layout for every screen size?

You need to make a new layout when your existing layouts do not work and you elect to make a new layout instead of solving the problem in other ways.

> Could you please help me figure out why a layout would look distorted ion a small device?

Your layout is perfectly fine, insofar as it is doing precisely what you told it to do:

- The video button is 42dp above the bottom of the layout
- The "or" line is 19dp above the video button
- The audio button is 22dp above the "or" line

That is 83dp plus the sizes of the various images, which clearly makes it too tall.

If that is not what you want it to do on a small screen, either:

- Come up with a different layout for `-small` devices, or
- Use dimension resources instead of hard-coded values, and use different values for those dimension for `-small` devices, or
- ...